# Adjusting the accordion

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I need to adjust this example to this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLaGr.png)

example: "codepen.io/tom-motl/pen/OJMMoeP"

Can anyone help me please? When I edit it, some things stop working ...

Answer (score 0):

My code -

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body">

        <div id="accordion-1">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1">
                  Item 1 > 1
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
              <div class="card-body">

                  <div id="accordion-1-1">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-1">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-1">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 1
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 1
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-2">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-2">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 2
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 2
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-3">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-3">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 3
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 3
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-2">
                  Item 1 > 2
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-2">
              <div class="card-body">
                Text 1 > 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
          Item 2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
      <div class="card-body">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-3">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
          Item 3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```